# linode server bandwidth

Tags: web-server, vps, bandwidth, traffic, linode

I am ready to deploy my startup on the web so i would like to start small and get a VPS from linode as i see many good reviews and see how its going...

the thing is that on their website they state:

**Transfer  200GB**

for their Linode 512

does this include incoming and outgoing traffic?

what if i get some unexpected traffic due to ddos, i dont know what else and all my traffic gets gone too fast?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linode don't charge you for incoming traffic, only outgoing. http://blog.linode.com/2011/09/01/linode-reduces-transfer-pricing/

Linode are also supposed to be pretty reasonable about people going just a few GB over their allowance.

You'll get an email in any case once you have used 80% of your allowance.

Comment: great... didnt know that...